# При архивации ошибка “libswiftCore.dylib” couldn’t be copied to “Frameworks”

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

При запуске на симуляторе и девайсе ошибки нет, при запуске архивации проекта выдает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код ошибки в виде скрина бесполезен. Приложите его, пожалуйста, в текстовом виде, соответствующе оформив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa pods используете в проекте?

Если да - чистите derived data у xcode.

Добавляется в таргете, который запускаете Run Script в Build Phases.

cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then
rm -fr Frameworks
fi